# Is it possible to create a simple spreadsheet template using python3 so that results are displayed in a CLI

Tags: python-3.x, new-operator

I have been tasked with showing certain information in a spreadsheet format in a linux cli environment.  I know I can manipulate excel with python but was asked to do so in a cli.  so it looks like a spread sheet.  Currently the only way I can think to do this is using ascii characters to create the columns and rows.  If someone has a better way to do so please let me know.  This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

var_1 = 'info'
var_2 = 'info'
var_3 = 'info'
var_4 = 'info'
var_5 = 'info'
var_6 = 'info'
var_7 = 'info'
var_8 = 'info'
var_9 = 'info'
var_10 = 'info'

print('--'*94
print(f'| heading1 ||| heading2 ||| heading3 |')
print('='*188)
print('='*188)
print(f'| {var_1} ||| {var_2} ||| {var_3} |')
```

That's just an example of the way I'm doing it. If possible is there a way to make the sheet react to the data in the cells?  I'm sure I'm asking for something that's just not possible but since googling this isn't working I figured I'd ask here.

Is there some module that would make this easier?  Sorry still a newbie with python and coding in general.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `pandas` to read/write data from spreadsheets and `https://pypi.org/project/terminaltables/` to output your data as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much!!